# image getting for JSON not Working

Tags: objective-c, json, post, uiimageview, base64

I tried to 1)POST image to URL and 2)get Image fro URL.

Posting worked :-

```
-(void)Send:(id)sender
{
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImageView.image);
    myString = [Base64 encode:imageData];
    NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?&image=%@",
                     myString];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.3.125:8090/SaveDollar/rest/classifieds/addTestImages"]]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];

    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

     con3 = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
       if(con3)
    {      webData3=[NSMutableData data];
        NSLog(@"Connection successfull");
        NSLog(@"GOOD Day My data %@",webData3);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"connection could not be made");
    }
}
```

But When I Get Image for JSON i got error:-

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{if (connection==con2)
    {
        al=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData2 options:0 error:nil];
        for (NSDictionary *diction in al)
        {
            NSString *geting =[diction valueForKey:@"image"];

             NSLog(@"geting is %@",geting);

            getdata = [NSData dataFromBase64String:geting ];
            //getdata = [Base64 decode:geting ];
             NSLog(@"getdata is %@",getdata);

            dataimages=[UIImage imageWithData:getdata];
            NSLog(@"dataImaeg is %@",dataimages);

            //[imagearray addObject:dataimages];


            myImageView.image=dataimages;

        }

    }
}
```

but When i getting image on JSON Data it's not worked. I got This error

Nov 10 14:25:35 Sricharans-iMac.local onlyGeting[3729] : ImageIO: PNG Q[10]U[1E]: invalid chunk type
Nov 10 14:25:35 Sricharans-iMac.local onlyGeting[3729] : ImageIO: PNG Q[10]U[1E]: invalid chunk type

Please tell me What wrong in my code .And Give me any Idea about my problem, image not getting.

Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: just offhand i thought you got one dictionary from json, though it can well be a dictionary of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Is your image getting uploaded? If it doesn't check out for codes of image posting, and also check out if the server backend is working properly

Comment: i have two ViewControl send and show.In SendViewControl is send image to server. it's worked nice but in ShowViewControl when i tried to get image for JSON it's worked

Comment: So now you are getting your image url in JSON in ShowViewController?